# How can I implement a non-jQuery version of data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm re-code a plugin `jQuery` I created, so I want take for create in pure `Javascript`

Most functions I can make fallowing [YouMightNotNeedjQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com) reference, but I don't have any idea to implement [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function for use in my plugin.

How to can I implement this function with `Javascript` pure?

Comment: Is it `element.dataset.key = value;`? It’s almost that at least…

Comment: I have no idea, I will check this way!

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data/Data.js

Comment: element.dataset will fail in IE prior to 11

Answer (score 4):

You can do it via `datasets`

HTML

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

Javascript

```
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Edit as per comment

HTML

```
<article id="electriccars">
    ...
</article>
```

Javascript

```
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');
article.setAttribute('data-columns', '3');
```

Example:

If you use `getAttribute()` the value is treated as a string, therefore it is not a like for like usage of jQuery `.data` as `.data` will assign objects and arrays to the data attr.

If you use `dataset` you will get a like for like usage as per jQuery.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69ukrpcf/

```
var myArr = ['item1', 'items2'];
```

jQuery Version

```
$('#one').data('foo', myArr);
var one = $('#one').data('foo');
console.log(one);
```

NON jQuery Version

```
var div = document.getElementById('two');
var two = div.dataset.foo = myArr;
console.log(two);
```

Comment: Maybe I can not use this way, I prefer values no change DOM or HTML

Comment: This isn't modifying the DOM, this is geting the values of data attributes that have already been set within the markup?

Comment: Perhaps it would make this answer more complete if the example also contained use-case for a dataset property that *isn't* first declared in the DOM. Like `article.dataset.whereDidThisComeFrom = 'JavaScript'; console.log(article.dataset);` People often use `jQuery.data` for *storing* data and I think that's the feature OP was looking for.

Comment: I need save some values linked by element, this case, normally is save in `data-attribute`? or what I saying no have sense?

Comment: This is my first time to create plugin, correct me if I say any wrose

Comment: Maybe I will try implement function referencing jQuery code in `github`

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to access data attr value as opposed to setting it. I've updated my answer. Obviously it is a very basic exmaple with no checking of current value etc etc.

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression, `data` function I meaning is this: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: `datasets` are used the same as `.data`. I have provided an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article about [how to work with data attributes here](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/70/how-to-save-information-on-a-dom-element-introduction-to-data-attributes-html5).

There are many ways to retrieve a data attribute with javascript :

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('randomid');
var articleId = domElement.getAttribute('data-articleid');
console.log(articleId);//Outputs 123
```

You can use too the datasets property of the dom element, however element.dataset will fail in old IE.